# Getting filenames from a folder in Sharepoint with VBA

Tags: file, vba, sharepoint, system, fso

I've done alot of research on this and found a number of help sites but still can't understand why this sometimes doesn't work.

I'm trying to access a sharepoint site (to which there are no restrictions for me) and extract all the files in a folder within that site.

Sometimes my Path works and it does it, other times it does not. I have a feeling it works if I've gone into the sharepoint site on my browser before but can't confirm that (because I just tried it again now and it doesnt work ARGGH). But the same code below has worked in the past.

It's failing on the File System Object function below

```
Public Function GetFullFileName(strfilepath As String, _
strFileNamePartial As String) As String
Dim objFS As Variant
Dim objFolder As Variant
Dim objFile As Variant
Dim intLengthOfPartialName As Integer
Dim strfilenamefull As String
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strfilepath)
'work out how long the partial file name is
intLengthOfPartialName = Len(strFileNamePartial)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'Test to see if the file matches the partial file name
    If Left(LCase(Replace(objFile.Name, " ", "")), intLengthOfPartialName) = LCase(strFileNamePartial) Then
    'get the full file name
        strfilenamefull = objFile.Name
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next objFile

'Return the full file name as the function's value
GetFullFileName = strfilenamefull
End Function
```

I get a "Run-time error '76': Path not found" when it gets to the GetFolder(strfilepath) code

The strfilepath is just a regular sharepoint site name (e.g. like \teams.uk\gm\FX\SharedDocuments\London\11) November 2013\20 November\Reports)

As mentioned I've tried different variations of the file path including DavWWW but nothing seems to work and I dont know what else to try.

Any advice please?

Thanks

Raiyan

Comment: May be because of network connection?

Comment: Don't think so - I'm able to go into the sharepoint site directly and access it?

Comment: Why are you using FileSystemObject to access documents on sharepoint site? SharePoint documents are located in virtual path created by SharePoint and FileSystemObject does not know anything about them. You should SharePoint API to access documents on sharepoint site.
Maybe you are using some sort of COM object?

Comment: What version of SharePoint is this? Where are you running the VBA from? For me your code works like a charm in Excel 2013 and SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Its Exel 2010 but not sure what Sharepoint version. Strangely, this same code has worked for me before so not sure why its not liking it now!? Yevgeny - using FSO in order to go through all the files in the folder and return the file that begins with my string variable. Im afraid my knowledge on Sharepoint API or even COM objects are limited but if there are any guides i'd be happy to read through them!

Answer (score 0):

The webclient service must be started to Access SharePoint using the FileSystemObject.

This service is often not started when you first log on.  However as you access SharePoint via the normal user interface it gets started.  I think this is why your code works inconsistently.

If you have admin rights on the local machine you can start the service manually (or using code).  However if you don't have rights then you can try a trick - it's clumsy but works.

Using VBA code open a known SharePoint folder in explorer view then close it.  This will trigger webclient to start.