# Extract attachment field file path to a different column

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

I exported a SharePoint list to Access and can view all columns (and its data) but the exported "Attachment" column has the tiny attachment icon which on click, opens a dialog box that has the file path within.

My problem is, I want to have this detail ("path") in a seperate column. Originally, I wanted to export the SharePoint list direct to Excel, but if I do that, in excel, the attachment column has boolean value (0 or 1) depending whether a row has attachment or not.

So far, the closest to all my options is Microsoft Access since at least I can see the attachment details but just to have it in a seperate column. I know VBA can do this but don't know what to do to get it work. Please any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When I click on attachment icon, the dialog shows file name, not a file path. Why would there be a file path since file is embedded in table? However, I did not export from SharePoint, just created an attachment field in Access table.

Comment: Tanks @braX for the first correction, you are correct, it's actually the file name, but when I click on open, it takes me to the SharePoint path for that image attachment and I can view the image. Your second point is actually wrong, I did export the data from SharePoint(List) to Access since access can atleast understand the attachment column. Tanks for ur quick response btw.

Comment: I think that comment was for @June7 ?

Comment: Yes it is. Tnx. Please I'm still patiently waiting for solution to this pleaseeee

Comment: An Access attachment field created in Access does not take you to a file location - it simply opens the embedded file in appropriate software. Attachment field is a type of multi-value field and I NEVER use multi-value fields. Unfortunately I am not familiar with SharePoint and cannot understand what you are describing. Might find this of interest https://sharepointmaven.com/why-you-should-never-use-sharepoint-lists-for-storing-files-and-attachments/.

Comment: Review https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e61afb14-6bfe-4982-be0f-34380a82ca6a/help-extracting-sharepoint-document-paths-using-vba and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215889/getting-filenames-from-a-folder-in-sharepoint-with-vba

Comment: Attachment filed is multivalue, what means there is a whole record with multiple fields stored in. To get that data select the attachment field within a recoredset, then set that  field to a new recordset, what reveals the data. See [Working with Attachment Fields](https://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/working-with-attachment-fields.html) Seems like you want to extract the FileURL that contains the sharepoint link

Comment: Another https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220160/how-to-extract-the-infopath-form-attachments-to-a-folder.